# LuaLaTeX printing while in a process_input_buffer hook

Tags: luatex

For MWE purposes, I'd like `LuaLaTeX` to print `<---Found it!` when `XYZ` is present in the input. I noticed that the `XYZ` text is found, but the `tex.print` call in the function I add to the buffer is only executed when I call a different one from Lua. Any insight or discussion on this works would be thoroughly appreciated. I have seen `callback.register("process_input_buffer", ...)` and `luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer",...)` be used to achieve this sort of thing, perhaps the issue lies there? I tried to use the `callback.register` method, but had some issues compiling.

Edit: looking at this wiki http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/Process_input_buffer, it appears that the `callback.register` method should be used.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
    function found_keyword(s)
        if string.find( s, "XYZ" ) then
            tex.print("<---Found it!")
        end
    end
luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", found_keyword, "found_keyword")
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}

Hello World.

XYZ  % shouldn't "<---Found it!" print here?
~ % still not printed
. % still not printed
\begin{luacode*}
    tex.print('') -- NOW it prints!
\end{luacode*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `luatexbase.add_to_callback` should be used in LuaLaTeX, `callback.register` in plain LuaTeX/ConTeXt/etc. Where do you expect `Found it!` to appear? After `XYZ`? Before? Why are you not just changing the return value from the callback?

Comment: I didn't realize returning the value was an option, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LuaTeX's `process_input_buffer` callback works at an extremely early stage, *before* TeX performs its usual processing ("eyes", "mouth", ...).

Let's examine what exactly is going on. The input line of interest is

```
XYZ  % shouldn't "<---Found it!" print here?
```

Importantly, Lua doesn't "know" that `%` is a comment character and that everything after `%` is ignored once LaTeX starts its job. Sure enough, `string.find` manages to locate 'XYZ'. And what does the Lua function do? Why, it places the string `<---Found it!` immediately after the line, effectively making it into

```
XYZ  % shouldn't "<---Found it!" print here?<---Found it!
```

Eventually, control is handed to LaTeX, which prints 'XYZ' since the string `shouldn't "<---Found it!" print here?<---Found it!` is behind a comment character.

The moral of the story? Be careful with comment characters.

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up comments/questions: Here's how I might re-write your code to make it ignore (LaTeX) comments. (The fearsome looking entity `[^\\]%%` means "a `%` character that's *not* preceded by a backslash character.)

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function found_keyword ( s )
    s = s:sub ( 1 , s:find ( "[^\\]%%" ) ) -- delete any comments from 's'
    if s:find ( "XYZ" ) then 
       return ( s .. " $\\leftarrow$ Found it!" )
    end
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer" , found_keyword , "found_keyword" )
```

```tex
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
Hello World. 

XYZ

% XYZ

ABC % XYZ 

100\% XYZ
\end{document}
```

Comment: If the "Found" string is placed after the comment character, then why does it appear in the subsequent luacode environment? "XYZ" wouldn't be found in that line? Even without a comment, it doesn't print until the luacode print.

Comment: I believe what you're suggesting would occur if I had `return s .. "<---Found it! \\TeX"` in my function.

Comment: @likethevegetable - My comment, "Be careful with comment characters", was meant to be very general. In the case of your code, the instruction `tex.print("<---Found it!")` gets placed after the comment character, but it actually lives in a bizarre state of suspended animation, to be resurrected later on, i.e., once `tex.print('')` is encountered. As i said, *be careful with comment characters*. I'll post an addendum to show how I think you *should* have programmed `found_keyword`, i.e., making it robust to the presence of comment characters

Comment: Thanks @Mico, I've found many of your posts helpful!